# Why does numpy.linalg.eig not satisfy "matrix dot eigen vector = eigen value dot eigen vector"?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Talk is cheap, here's the code.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
from numpy import linalg as nlin
from numpy import dot,array
def check_eig(matrix):
    eigen_values,eigen_vector_matrix=nlin.eig(test_matrix)
    print('list of eigen values:','\n',eigen_values)
    print('matrix of eigen vectors:','\n',eigen_vector_matrix)
    for i in range(len(eigen_values)):
        print('='*5)
        print('current eigen value:',eigen_values[i])
        print('current eigen vector:',eigen_vector_matrix[:,i])                
        print(dot(matrix,eigen_vector_matrix[:,i])==dot(eigen_values[i],eigen_vector_matrix[:,i]))
        print('-'*5)
    pass
if __name__=='__main__':
    test_matrix=array([[2,4,7,3],[3,4,1,9],[2,3,6,1],[5,5,10,11]])
    check_eig(test_matrix)
    pass
```

And the output is:

```sh
list of eigen values: 
[19.53900138+0.j         -0.67342882+0.j          2.06721372+2.80827583j
2.06721372-2.80827583j]
matrix of eigen vectors: 
[[ 0.33504457+0.j         -0.94360845+0.j         -0.1790607 -0.21350827j
-0.1790607 +0.21350827j]
[ 0.51694078+0.j          0.23884601+0.j          0.79630803+0.j
0.79630803-0.j        ]
[ 0.21990713+0.j          0.14936312+0.j         -0.33955605-0.22141925j
-0.33955605+0.22141925j]
[ 0.75641141+0.j          0.17391471+0.j         -0.07359501+0.34424407j
-0.07359501-0.34424407j]]
=====
current eigen value: (19.53900137643081+0j)
current eigen vector: [0.33504457+0.j 0.51694078+0.j 0.21990713+0.j 0.75641141+0.j]
[False False False False]
-----
=====
current eigen value: (-0.6734288183538105+0j)
current eigen vector: [-0.94360845+0.j  0.23884601+0.j  0.14936312+0.j  0.17391471+0.j]
[False False False False]
-----
=====
current eigen value: (2.06721372096151+2.808275832055751j)
current eigen vector: [-0.1790607 -0.21350827j  0.79630803+0.j         -0.33955605-0.22141925j
-0.07359501+0.34424407j]
[False False False False]
-----
=====
current eigen value: (2.06721372096151-2.808275832055751j)
current eigen vector: [-0.1790607 +0.21350827j  0.79630803-0.j         -0.33955605+0.22141925j
-0.07359501-0.34424407j]
[False False False False]
-----
```

This is weird; can anybody tell me why the method in numpy.linalg.eig does not satisfy the basic equation "matrix dot eigen vector = eigen value dot eigen vector"?

Answer (score 0):

Rounding error.

If we replace the `==` with `-` we see that the differences are all really small, 10⁻¹⁵ and similar.

This is generally true with floating-point maths on computers; comparing them exactly with `==` produces unreliable results, sometimes matching, sometimes not.

When we need to compare floating-point numbers, we need to subtract them, take the absolute value and check that it's less than some tolerance (usually called "epsilon", although that also has a somewhat different technical meaning).

The test passes if we write it like this:

> abs(matrix dot eigen vector - eigen value dot eigen vector) < 10⁻¹⁴

```
print(abs(dot(matrix, eigen_vector_matrix[:,i]) - dot(eigen_values[i], eigen_vector_matrix[:,i])) < 1e-14)
```

There's a whole field of study, "numerical stability", around when the rounding error remains small. For example, the textbook formulas for calculating standard deviation have this problem — the rounding errors can become big if they're implemented directly — so a different formula has to be used to calculate standard deviation on a computer.

Comment: `np.allclose` is a handy function for comparing numeric arrays.